# How can I recover files that have dissapeared?

Tags: dual-boot, filesystem, ntfs

I'm honestly in tears, I've just lost 60GB of music I've been collecting for over 15 years.

I mounted a drive to /mnt and moved all the music files over to it. When it finished I checked that the files were all there and then shut down my computer and rebooted it into Windows. The files were not there, shut down again and booted back into Linux and they've all vanished. I have no idea what to do. Have they actually been deleted?

Any help is hugely appreciated :(

Comment: Probably they're somewhere on your system, just not where you expect.  More details, like was the target a separate disk?  where exactly did you mount it, and what filesystem was on it? How did you copy, and how did you check that the files were at the target location?

Comment: You can try this https://www.diskinternals.com/uneraser/how-to-recover-permanently-deleted-files-in-windows-10/

Comment: @ubfan1 They are separate disks. I mounted the disk to /mnt and moved the files into the new location using Caja (Ubuntu MATE File Explorer), then I restarted my system and they all disappeared.

Comment: Did you *re*-mount the disk after restarting? mounts aren't persistent across reboots unless you add them to `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Yea I've tried remounting the disk. There was a folder called "System Volume Information" which is still there. But the other folders have all gone. I've even downloaded testdisk and tried recovering any deleted files, they're all gone.

Comment: First place to check is the root's /mnt directory.  Maybe the mount failed, or was already on /media, or...  So, before mounting anything, look in /mnt.  Did you let the copy finish (all disk activity stopped) before reboot?

Comment: @ubfan1Yes, it had all stopped completely, I listened to a load of tracks in the new location before rebooting. I've tried looking into /mnt with the mount and without the mount, the files I've moved are all gone.

Comment: And to top things off I think the partition is now corrupt; the type is listed as "RAW" under windows disk management.

Comment: What exact mount command did you use? If you used the device  sdb instead of the partition sdbx, the partition table would have been overwritten, but the files are there, accessible if you mount the disk with the -oloop option (treat the disk like a big file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in the end by switching over to windows and running chkdsk, after it completed a few hours later all of my files reappeared.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (maybe after a waiting period), so others know this has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

If NTFS & RAW, you want to get to this screen:

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#NTFS_Boot_sector_recovery

select [Advanced] instead of [Analyze] and select [BackupBS]
[HowTo] Repair the bootsector of a Windows partition  - YannBuntu

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1926510

If files were written into partition, then Windows scan tools or photorec may work. Windows tools may be better as they can get full file name. Photorec only recovers by type with file extension. If photos you can often can rename with info from within the photo. You have to use another drive, the backup drive you should have already had?

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step